# L2TP/IPSec VPN Client on Raspberry Pi Jessie?

Tags: raspbian, server, windows, vpn

Is there any package for the Raspberry out there, to setup a L2TP/IPSec connection from Raspberry Pi (Jessie) to my Windows server (i.e. `vpn-server l2tp/ipsec`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a guide [here](https://gist.github.com/mietek/4877cd74423bf6925b92) describing the process for Jessie. Looks like it's based on [LibreSwan](https://libreswan.org) and [PPP](https://wiki.debian.org/PPP). There are *many* dense looking configuration options in there which make it impractical for me to provide a full run-down in a single answer I'm afraid.

Comment: The link provided is a guide on how to set up a VPN server, not a client.

Answer (score 0):

[This guide](https://github.com/hwdsl2/setup-ipsec-vpn/blob/master/docs/clients.md#linux-vpn-clients) is a client-side config I'm about to start working with.